# How do you scale KML path width proportional to the zoom

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I have this example of using Wordpress which is adding a KML to a Google Maps APIv3 implementation.  One of my pet peeves is that I have not been able to find a way to set a relative width on the KML file stroke width so that when you zoom out it doesn't look like blog of color.

http://mountainbiketetons.org/region/trails/teton-valley/tetons/aspen/